# Element not going completely fullscreen

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, fullscreen, jupyter-notebook

Problem: the plot below is only partially fullscreen. How do I stretch this element to fill the entire viewable area of the screen upon fullscreen?

[image: Plot in fullscreen]

The fullscreen function I am using:

```
function toggleFullscreen(elem) { //function to make element (cell) fullscreen on most browsers
      elem = elem || document.documentElement;
      if (!document.fullscreenElement && !document.mozFullScreenElement &&
        !document.webkitFullscreenElement && !document.msFullscreenElement) {
        if (elem.requestFullscreen) {
          elem.requestFullscreen();
        } else if (elem.msRequestFullscreen) {
          elem.msRequestFullscreen();
        } else if (elem.mozRequestFullScreen) {
          elem.mozRequestFullScreen();
        } else if (elem.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
          elem.webkitRequestFullscreen(Element.ALLOW_KEYBOARD_INPUT);
        }
      } 
    }
```

Callback to fullscreen:

```
var $saved_cell = $('.cell.code_cell.rendered.selected > div.output_wrapper > div.output > div > div.output_subarea.output_html.rendered_html');

$saved_cell.each(
        function() { toggleFullscreen(this) } ).css({
            'background-color' : 'rgb(244,244,244)',
            'position': 'absolute',
            'z-index': '9999',
            'min-width': '100%',
            'height': '100vh',
            'margin': '0',
            'padding': '0',
            'overflow': 'auto'
        }); //expand selected cell
```

Also, here is a screenshot of the DOM around the selected element:

[image: DOM]

Answer (score 0):

You need to to change or remove the width and height that is set on the graphics `<svg>` items themselves. Simply making the div larger won't automatically resize the graphics.

An alternative approach that would probably be simpler (in my opinion) might be to copy the children nodes from the `<div class="svg-container" ...>` and put them into another container that is/can be 100% that you can just show/hide, modify the width and height on the copied `<svg>` elements so they aren't fixed, and toggle the view full-screen. This way you won't mess up the 'normal' view that will probably want to maintain.

You can use JQuery's <kbd>[.find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/)</kbd> and <kbd>[.clone()](http://api.jquery.com/clone/)</kbd> to get to the div mentioned above (instead of trying to walk that nasty structure) and make a copy in the space you want to show at 100%. Then manipulate `<svg>` width and height as you desire.